# Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular-material, node-modules

hope all doing good,
I did node version(v14.18.0) update in my project, after I'm getting module not found issue (screenshot attached), waiting for your suggestion.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to install packege and make sure they are listed in package.json dependency

Comment: Thank you, i deleted the node_modules and re-installed the packages to fix.